# PHP ini_get() and php.ini are not in sync

Tags: php, memory-limit

My php.ini has a memory_limit of 256M. phpinfo() reflects this. But from within PHP, ini_get('memory_limit'); returns 32M. My fatal errors for exceeding memory limit also say that the max is 32M.

Any ideas why phpinfo() is lying to me?

Answer (score 1):

are one of the results from cli, and the other from web?

Comment: No, I created a phpinfo.php file that just dumps phpinfo(); and I did a die(ini_get('memory_limit')); in the other php file, so they're both from the web.

Comment: This is likely.  Check the results of `phpinfo()`, the list of php.ini files *and directories scanned for additional ini files* should be present.

Comment: Interesting. I have:

Configuration File (php.ini) Path /usr/lib
Loaded Configuration File /[path_to_public_html]/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files (none)
additional .ini files parsed (none)

What do you make of that? What's the difference between "configuration file" and "loaded configuration file?"

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to override php.ini parameters in the Apache configuration files.

Depending on the system, their location may vary, but check anything under /etc/apache2, /etc/apache2/conf.d, /etc/apache2/sites-enabled

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting the limit with PHP code as a test?

ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');